# Reading raw json data of a table into df table?

Tags: python, html, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to download the json data into a df table from: "http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/lrbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=0&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ002475"
 , which is the raw data of table at bottom of this page "http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/Index?type=web&code=SZ002475#"

The json page appears to be simple json data as"[{\"SECURITYCODE\":\"002475.SZ\",\"REPORTTYPE\":\"1\",\"TYPE\":\"4\",\"REPORTDATE\":\"2019/9/30 0:00:00\",\"TOTALOPERATEREVE\":\"37836138416.35\",\"OPERATEREVE\":\"37836138416.35\",........"

However, nothing was returned from the following codes:

```
url ="http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/lrbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=0&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ002475"
df = pd.read_json(url) 
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the given URL.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url="http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/lrbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=0&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ002475"
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
out_df = pd.DataFrame(eval(json_data))
print(out_df)
```

It is working, please see below screenshot
[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks. I tried and not working. And, I updated the URL in the code. Please take a look :)