# Reading Json into dataframe or other ways to store Json data in Python?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I am trying to download the json data into a df table from: "http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/lrbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=0&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ002475" , which is the raw data of table at bottom of this page "http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/Index?type=web&code=SZ002475#". 
The json page appears to be simple json data as"[{\"SECURITYCODE\":\"002475.SZ\",\"REPORTTYPE\":\"1\",\"TYPE\":\"4\",\"REPORTDATE\":\"2019/9/30 0:00:00\",\"TOTALOPERATEREVE\":\"37836138416.35\",\"OPERATEREVE\":\"37836138416.35\",........"
However, nothing was returned from the following codes. On the other hand, can python manipulate json in other ways?

```
url ="http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/lrbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=0&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ002475"
df = pd.read_json(url) 
print(df)
```

Comment: you can use json library to convert your json file to dictionary and it is pretty useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading raw json data of a table into df table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205543/reading-raw-json-data-of-a-table-into-df-table)

Comment: Please do not post the same issue twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json downloaded from the url was downloaded in the wrong format, for example `"人民币]"` was converted to `"\xe4\xba\xba\xe6\xb0\x91\xe5\xb8\x81\\"`, and the `JsonReader` in `pandas` couldn't handle that. You can download the raw data with requests and convert it to json instead

```
res = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.read_json(res)
print(df)
```

Output

```
  SECURITYCODE  REPORTTYPE  ...  MINORITYCINCOME_YOY CURRENCY
0    002475.SZ           1  ...          1750.291509      人民币
1    002475.SZ           1  ...           227.405535      人民币
2    002475.SZ           1  ...           217.222803      人民币
3    002475.SZ           1  ...            35.852546      人民币
4    002475.SZ           1  ...          -225.088170      人民币
5    002475.SZ           1  ...          -595.215183      人民币

[6 rows x 97 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

## "can python manipulate json in other ways?"

#### YES: the JSON module can take a JSON string and convert it to a dictionary structure:

```
import requests as rq
import json


url = "http://emweb.securities.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/lrbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=0&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ002475"

res = rq.get(url).json()
lst_of_res_dicts = json.loads(res)

for res_dict in lst_of_res_dicts:
    print()
    print(type(res_dict))
    print(res_dict.keys())
    print(res_dict['TYPE'])
    # print etc
```

Which yields:

```
<class 'dict'>

dict_keys(['SECURITYCODE', 'REPORTTYPE', 'TYPE', 'REPORTDATE', 'TOTALOPERATEREVE', 'OPERATEREVE', 'INTREVE', 'PREMIUMEARNED', 'COMMREVE', 'OTHERREVE', 'TOTALOPERATEEXP', 'OPERATEEXP', 'INTEXP', 'COMMEXP', 'RDEXP', 'SURRENDERPREMIUM', 'NETINDEMNITYEXP', 'NETCONTACTRESERVE', 'POLICYDIVIEXP', 'RIEXP', 'OTHEREXP', 'OPERATETAX', 'SALEEXP', 'MANAGEEXP', 'FINANCEEXP', 'ASSETDE
VALUELOSS', 'FVALUEINCOME', 'INVESTINCOME', 'INVESTJOINTINCOME', 'EXCHANGEINCOME', 'OPERATEPR
OFIT', 'NONOPERATEREVE', 'NONLASSETREVE', 'NONOPERATEEXP', 'NONLASSETNETLOSS', 'SUMPROFIT', '
INCOMETAX', 'NETPROFIT', 'COMBINEDNETPROFITB', 'PARENTNETPROFIT', 'MINORITYINCOME', 'KCFJCXSYJLR', 'BASICEPS', 'DILUTEDEPS', 'OTHERCINCOME', 'PARENTOTHERCINCOME', 'MINORITYOTHERCINCOME', 'SUMCINCOME', 'PARENTCINCOME', 'MINORITYCINCOME', 'TOTALOPERATEREVE_YOY', 'OPERATEREVE_YOY', 'INTREVE_YOY', 'PREMIUMEARNED_YOY', 'COMMREVE_YOY', 'OTHERREVE_YOY', 'TOTALOPERATEEXP_YOY','OPERATEEXP_YOY', 'INTEXP_YOY', 'COMMEXP_YOY', 'RDEXP_YOY', 'SURRENDERPREMIUM_YOY', 'NETINDEMNITYEXP_YOY', 'NETCONTACTRESERVE_YOY', 'POLICYDIVIEXP_YOY', 'RIEXP_YOY', 'OTHEREXP_YOY', 'OPERATETAX_YOY', 'SALEEXP_YOY', 'MANAGEEXP_YOY', 'FINANCEEXP_YOY', 'ASSETDEVALUELOSS_YOY', 'FVALUEINCOME_YOY', 'INVESTINCOME_YOY', 'INVESTJOINTINCOME_YOY', 'EXCHANGEINCOME_YOY', 'OPERATEPROFIT_YOY', 'NONOPERATEREVE_YOY', 'NONLASSETREVE_YOY', 'NONOPERATEEXP_YOY', 'NONLASSETNETLOSS_YOY', 'SUMPROFIT_YOY', 'INCOMETAX_YOY', 'NETPROFIT_YOY', 'COMBINEDNETPROFITB_YOY', 'PARENTNETPROFIT_YOY', 'MINORITYINCOME_YOY', 'KCFJCXSYJLR_YOY', 'BASICEPS_YOY', 'DILUTEDEPS_YOY', 'OTHERCINCOME_YOY', 'PARENTOTHERCINCOME_YOY', 'MINORITYOTHERCINCOME_YOY', 'SUMCINCOME_YOY', 'PARENTCINCOME_YOY', 'MINORITYCINCOME_YOY', 'CURRENCY'])

4
...
```